# Expo EAS build failing on Prebuild

Tags: expo

The build was working fine before installing expo-image-picker. But it's not working now even after removing the package.

This is the build command.

```
eas build -p android --profile preview2
```

[image]

Both android and ios build failing.
It looks like an image error, i removed all the images from my app but the issue still persists

Here's my package.json

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@eva-design/eva": "^2.1.1",
    "@expo/webpack-config": "~0.16.2",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "~1.17.3",
    "@react-native-masked-view/masked-view": "^0.2.6",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.3.1",
    "@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs": "^6.2.1",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.10",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.6.2",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.2.1",
    "@sentry/react-native": "^3.4.2",
    "@ui-kitten/components": "^5.1.2",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "expo": "~45.0.0",
    "expo-application": "~4.1.0",
    "expo-blur": "~11.1.0",
    "expo-constants": "~13.1.1",
    "expo-dev-client": "~0.9.6",
    "expo-device": "~4.2.0",
    "expo-image-picker": "~13.1.1",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~11.3.0",
    "expo-localization": "~13.0.0",
    "expo-notifications": "~0.15.2",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.15.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.3.0",
    "expo-updates": "~0.13.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "moment": "^2.29.3",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.68.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.2.1",
    "react-native-modern-datepicker": "^1.0.0-beta.91",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.8.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.2.4",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.11.1",
    "react-native-svg": "12.3.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.1.0",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.7",
    "sentry-expo": "^4.2.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.182",
    "@types/react": "~17.0.21",
    "@types/react-native": "~0.67.6",
    "@types/react-native-vector-icons": "^6.4.10",
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.25",
    "@types/styled-components-react-native": "^5.1.3",
    "ts-node": "^10.7.0",
    "typescript": "~4.3.5"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue. I've found that `jimp-compact` is a dependency of `@expo/image-utils@0.3.20`.

Comment: @JoeMcLean So my problem was I used expo to optimize my images, it turned out somehow one image converted to heic, which was giving the error, removing the image solved the issue for me. try to investigate the error logs.

Comment: Thanks for keying me in on that. I have used Expo to optimize my images as well, but I just have `.png` and `.jpg` files.

Comment: @JoeMcLean mime-type is the issue, not the extension
 `file --mime-type *`    use this command on ./assets folder to check all the mime-types.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up removing all the images I optimized with `expo-optimize`, deleted `node_modules` and rebuild `yarn` or `npm install` and that did the trick for me. Fortunately I had a back up of the images.